# vb LINQ to dataset to extract single data point

Tags: vb.net, linq, dataset

I'm trying to pull a variable from a datatable via a linq to a dataset, but the code below won't compile - compiler says that ID and EXCHANGE "aren't a member of DataRow", but the datatable "UDLY" is populated and ID and EXCHANGE are field names.... so I don't know what this means, any help please?

```
Dim DS As New DataSet()
Dim QRY = DS.Tables("UDLY").AsEnumerable

Dim NME = From x In QRY
                  Where x.ID = 1        'won't compile x.ID - "...not a member of Datarow"
                  Select x.EXCHANGE     'won't compile x.EXCHANGE - "ditto"

MsgBox("NME= " & NME)
```

Comment: When do you fill data into dataset?

Comment: Try this : - http://hastebin.com/opoxazehut.avrasm

Comment: I populated the datatable using visual studio "show data table" cmd and then entered some samle data

Comment: ...it compiles, but  I get an error on execution saying "argumentnullexception was handled".....looks like my dataset DS isn't being populated?....but when I open the datatable in the server explorer view i can see data?

Comment: just check  `DS.Tables("UDLY").rows.count`

Comment: code won't run past the ``Dim QRY = DS.Tables("UDLY").AsEnumerable``line...DS not being populated from Table UDLY as I thought it was?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/ucugusohil.tex  i got this to work, but there could be a simpler way to populate the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is self explanatory. In your query `x` represents a DataRow and `DataRow` does not contain a definition of `ID` or `EXCHANGE`. You need to specify the column name you want to access within that DataRow like this: `x("ID")`. So your final query should look like this:-

```
Dim NME = (From x In QRY
          Where x("ID") = 1        
          Select x("EXCHANGE")).FirstOrDefault()
```

Please note I am using `FirstOrDefault` here to fetch the first matching `EXCHANGE`. If you don't use that it will return you a collection and then you will have to use a `ForEach` loop to fetch the data.

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Wingedpantha

Answer (score 0):

A better approach I think would be this, assuming that `EXCHANGE` is of type double.

```
Dim exchange = (From r In dt.AsEnumerable() 
                Where r.Field(Of Integer)("ID") = 1 
                Select r.Field(Of Double)("EXCHANGE"))                    
                .FirstOrDefault()
```